# How to permanently stop PDFs scaling when printing?

Tags: pdf, printing, pdf-reader

I have a client that is provided with PDF's by a 3rd party. These PDF's are always 9" x 6".

They have a printer which was recommended by the 3rd party, and have the correct paper size setup in settings and have the correct media.

When it comes to printing the PDF's it always scales it down to 89% which then means they are printing outside of the boxes on the supplied media.

Could someone tell me how to force the scale to be 100%? It should be noted that we have no control over the generation of the PDF's.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You did not indicate which PDF reader you are using, so I will assume Adobe.

If the printer is setup to use the proper paper, then you should be able to select **`Actual size`** in the print window. Check the other properties to ensure it is using the correct paper size loaded in the printer.

[image]

You can [Create Print Presets](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/basic-pdf-printing-tasks.html#create_print_presets) by opening the file, go to `File > Properties` then the `Advanced` tab. Under `Print Dialog Presets`, set the Page Scaling to `None`. Save the file and now each time it is printed, it will default to `Actual Size`. This is specific to that file as it saves the setting in the file itself.

Comment: Hi sorry about that. Yes you are correct... the problem is they have to do this every time. I'm looking for a way to select this option by default

Comment: Added details for presets.

Comment: The file is only used once. Over 100 are generated each day for printing. Would that still work?

Comment: I don't think so. Somehow you have to set that globally for Acrobat.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do. But unfortunately I can't find this information anywhere :/

Comment: Only way I believe is at the source where file is created. That way it comes to you ready to print. Is it possible to ask those generating it if they can help you?

Comment: The company that generate them provided the printer and they say it should work